# Output of React Native packager on Linux

Tags: linux, react-native

I see no output of **React Native packager** on **Linux (Ubuntu 17.04)** and **react-native** **0.51.0**  even though it is running.
A teammate uses **Windows 10** and after `react-native run-android` he gets a new window with output from the packager.

Is there a way to see the packager's output ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Before running `react-native run-android` try running `react-native start` in a different terminal, this command will start the packager manually.

**PS:** `react-native run-android` is optional if you didn't change one of native android files, you can just start the packager and then reload the already installed app.